# Explanation of density rewriting?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function, integral

Can somebody please explain the math behind this statement to me?  I am not sure how they represent the left hand side by that integral and finally how it is proportional to that.
\begin{align}
p(S_{t+1}|z_{t+1}) &=\int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})d\mathbb{P}(S_t|z^{t+1})  \\
                  &\propto \int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})p(z_{t+1}|S_t)d\mathbb{P}(S_t|z^t)
\end{align}
where $z^{t+1}=(z_1,...,z_t)$

Also, are these two equivalent?

$$\int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})d\mathbb{P}(S_t|z^{t+1}) \stackrel{?}{=} 
\int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})p(S_t|z^{t+1})dS_t$$

as in, is that the correct way to interpret integrating with respect to a probability measure?

Comment: The $z^{t+1}$ is different from the $z_{t+1}$

Comment: For context this equation is on page 4 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.5262v3.pdf

Comment: Your second line of mathematics is incorrectly copied.

Comment: @Glen_b, sorry but I don't see it.  Can you point out the mistake?

Comment: I fixed it ... you were missing the $\int$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out

\begin{align}
p(S_{t+1}|z_{t+1}) &=\int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})d\mathbb{P}(S_t|z^{t+1})  \\
&=\int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})p(S_t|z^{t+1})dS_t\\
&\propto \int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})p(z^{t+1}|S_t)p(St)dS_t\hspace{1in}\text{by Bayes Rule}\\
&\propto \int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})p(z_{t+1}|S_t)p(z^t|S_t)p(St)dS_t\hspace{.3in}\text{Conditional Independce}\\
&\propto \int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})p(z_{t+1}|S_t)p(S_t|z^t)dS_t\hspace{.78in}\text{by Bayes Rule}\\
&\propto \int p(S_{t+1}|S_t,z_{t+1})p(z_{t+1}|S_t)d\mathbb{P}(S_t|z^t)
\end{align}